# Is it possible to download a file from docker to local drive

Tags: python, docker, plotly-dash

I have a Python dash app that has a button for downloading Excel file from the docker. Below is a minimal example for that purpose. When FOLDER is my local drive button works as intended, and downloading starts. However, when FOLDER is the docker path (/app/data) button does not work and I get this:

[image]

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Thanks!!

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html
from flask import send_from_directory

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SIMPLEX])
server = app.server

FOLDER = 'C:/TEST'
# FOLDER = '/app/data'

app.layout = html.Div([
dbc.Button(
    children="Test",
    href=f'/{FOLDER}/abc.xlsx',
    download="abc.xlsx",
    external_link=True
   )
])


@server.route(f'/{FOLDER}/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
   try:
       return send_from_directory(FOLDER, filename, as_attachment=True)
   except Exception as e:
       return str(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   # app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', port='8085', debug=True)
   app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [volume mounting](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) with docker - by design, the paths inside of a container are not accessible from the parent system, but you could volume mount a specific directory, either via the docker cli or via docker compose, to mount a specific directory inside of your container to a path outside your disk, and then change the URL you're loading from to pull the data from there.

in docker compose, for example:

```
services:
  frontend:
    image: python3.9 #or whatever you like
    volumes:
      - C:/test/:/app/data
```

And now your container can write to /app/data, and you'll see it at C:/test/.

There are plenty of ways to harden this up (pass the directory in via an .env var, for example) - you might also have better luck serving files from a relative path inside of your flask app, but if you need them outside of the container, volume mounting is your best bet

Comment: Thanks for your comment! One thing I could not get it. You said "inside of a container are not accessible from the parent system" but `os.listdir(FOLDER)` actually gives me what is under /app/data. So we can only see inside of a folder but can not download a file from there? Because I don't want to write to /app/data. Download a file from /app/data.

Comment: Oh I see - looking at this again it may be much simpler:
`FOLDER = '/app/data'`
`f'/{FOLDER}/<path:filename>'`
gives you a path of `//app/data/<path:filename>' - which looks like a network path. Try removing the slash from your FOLDER variable?

Comment: I tried now but not working